# python and Basemap and remove Mexico/Canada from view

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am using Basemap within Matplotlib to draw a map of the United States.  However, I cannot seem to be able to remove Mexico or Canada to just have the US shown.  I need to draw the states as well.  Currently, my code is:

```
self.map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-119, llcrnrlat=22, urcrnrlon=-64,
                               urcrnrlat=49, projection='lcc', lat_1=33, lat_2=45,
                               lon_0=-95, resolution='i', area_thresh=10000,ax=self.axes)

self.map.drawcoastlines()
self.map.drawcountries()
self.map.drawstates()
self.figure.canvas.draw()
```

This draws the US with some Mexico and Canada shown.  If i comment out `self.map.drawcountries()`, then the southern and northern US borders are removed, so this doesn't help.  If i comment out `self.map.drawcoastlines()`, this removes the East and West borders.  I cannot find any other command that allows me to have just the US (with states) drawn.

Any ideas?  Thanks!